# Why the option label are always put in before command in Auctex mode and How to fix it

Tags: emacs, auctex

dMy editing LaTeX environment is Emacs with Auctex. When I used C-c C-s to create section or C-c Ret to create environments, I am always asked to input some label for options the section or environments. But after I input the labels, the displayed label always are put right before the commands. What reason for this result and How can I fix it?

Any advise will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

The error is illustrated as followed snapshot.

[image]

I have just found the problem arises always after some packages loaded in idle time. So I comment these codes out and then the issue disappeared. But I don't understand the true reason of this problem. Any friend could help me?

```
 ;{{ idle require other stuff
 (setq idle-require-idle-delay 3)
 (setq idle-require-symbols '(init-misc-lazy
                         init-which-func
                         init-fonts
                         init-hs-minor-mode
                         init-stripe-buffer
                         init-textile
                         init-csv
                         init-writting
                         init-elnode
                         init-doxygen
                         init-pomodoro
                         init-emacspeak
                         init-artbollocks-mode
                         init-semantic))
   (idle-require-mode 1) ;; starts loading
   ; }}
```

The configuration file are downloaded from https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d

Comment: I hope you don't really pretend someone looking into 301 configuration files for you.  This problem has clearly to do with some weird configuration.  The best I can suggest you is to do a binary search to find at least the offending file, then someone could take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for you instructive help. As your said, I found the configuration file that producing problem is  init-misc-lazy. Now when this file is commented out, the problem disappears.

Comment: Ok, I tried that file (but I had to comment some lines because they require other packages I don't intend to install just for a test) and I cannot reproduce the problem you reported.  A personal note: I don't like these super giant configuration packages, if you don't know how to debug possible bugs they are unmanageable.  I rather prefer to pick up a few lines and include them in my personal configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I'm just newbie of Emacs and emacs lisp is more strange to me. But this configuration makes me quickly enjoy working with Emacs, although sometimes brings a little trouble. Anyway, thanks your advice. Now I am trying to learn emacs lisp.

Comment: This question is not related to TeX/LaTeX. This problems comes from the emacs configuration files downloaded.